# How to set default app for the fan page

Tags: facebook-apps

Please help me to how to set the default landing app for the fan page?or default landing page for the fan page?I am developing the app with .net

I tried in the new versions and i couldn't get in older version in the managepermission tab of the fan page there is an option called the Default Landing Tab. but i couldn't find  in the new version .please help me i struckedup here a lot.

this is the older version way of setting up the default landing tab for fanpage.

https://www.socialappshq.com/help/change-default-landing-page-for-facebook-page

Comment: Friends this post making me terrified for default landing tab. http://techcrunch.com/2012/02/29/death-of-the-facebook-default-landing-tab/

Answer (score 0):

Facebook landing pages can no longer display one of their custom applications because their default landing tab that non-fans first see when they visit. Facebook can still have these custom applications but now it cannot be use as the default, now the timeline will always be the default page for all Facebook users. It is most likely done to stop the excess use of the Like Gate or may be hiding something users wanted behind the landing page.

*taken from http://thenewsstream.blogspot.com/2012/04/things-facebook-users-need-to-know.html